# EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception

Tags: hibernate, junit, hsqldb, openejb

I got stock with this thing. All my unit testings worked fine except for this one.
I already have a bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_place", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "manager_id"))
public class PlaceBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "place_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getPlaceId() {
       return this.placeId;
    }

    public void setPlaceId(Integer placeId) {
       this.placeId = palceId;
    }
........
}
```

Then i have a dao. 
Then in my test i did it this way...

```
@EJB
private MyDao myDao;

@Test
public void testSomething(){
PlaceBean placeBean = new PlaceBean();
    placeBean.setOwnerId(1);
    placeBean.setCategoryId(1);
    placeBean.setProfile("world");

    myDao.makePersistent(placeBean);
    assertNotNull(placeBean);
}
```

There is no problem with findAll(). The only problem is when inserting. I'm using HSQL for 
my unit test. i can tell that the my configurations are okay because other test works fine.

When performing unit test on this one, this is the trace:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
        org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:363)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)
        at $Proxy62.makePersistent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sprasia.rest.dao.nstudio.MyDaoTest.testSomething(MyDaoTest.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2966)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3477)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3SaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3SaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:734)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:726)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:722)
        at com.sprasia.rest.dao.GenericHbDao.makePersistent(GenericHbDao.java:75)
        at com.sprasia.rest.dao.impl.nstudio.MyDaoImpl.makePersistent(MyDaoImpl.java:1)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.invoke(CdiInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.access$000(CdiInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor$1.call(CdiInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.aroundInvoke(CdiInterceptor.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:176)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:138)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:237)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:189)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:253)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:248)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:279)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TBL_PLACE
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:508)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:508)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
        ... 83 more
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TBL_PLACE
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRangeVariableForDataChange(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 89 more
```

Comment: Did you check your account privileges? Can your account write to db?

Comment: yes. I tried writing in my other unit test. and it was successful.

Comment: Which one is the problem ? Is it that you can not write to to DB or just getting this exception messages or both of them???

Comment: i cant write to my in-memory DB then that is the exception message,,

Comment: If persisting data has no problems, as far as I know you can ignore this logged JDBC exceptions since Hibernate takes care of them.

Comment: i cant persist. that is why i have this traces. but what made me wonder was that using other beans, i can persist..but using the bean i posted as example, i cant persist..it give and error and that error trace...

Comment: I am sure you had tried it and checked it, but you can check that database schema and the bean matches.

Comment: when i do this `myDao.makepersistent(myBean)` myBean is unknown ? ?